# getText in EditText returns null value

Tags: android, textview

setText works fine but getText doesn't retrieve value

```
 public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


    taskRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Tasks");
    post_title = (EditText) root.findViewById(R.id.post_task_title);
    post_description = root.findViewById(R.id.post_task_description);
    post_price = root.findViewById(R.id.post_price);
    post_title.setText("hi");

    title = post_title.getText().toString();
    description = post_description.getText().toString();
    price = post_price.getText().toString();
```

Comment: You even have compiler error that `getText` may produce null pointer exception

Comment: No, such error. When Trying to make toast it shows empty String

Comment: Did you try to set the initial value in the xml?

Comment: I haven't set any initial value in xml

Comment: Please share the XML layout as well, it would be easier to figure out what could be wrong,

Comment: Got answer wraping getText in onClickListener, I was trying to recieve text after immediate after declaring EditText